# Checking for possibly null values in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL Database modeling this classes.

```
Public Class Language
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Articles As List(Of Article)
End Class

Public Class Article
  Public Property Dated as DateTime?
End Class
```

I want to get a list of Languages and also the date of the last article

But I have to check if the Articles have items, if the article have a valid date.

What's the correct way to do the query? I've done this so far:

```
  Dim query = From x In context.Languages
              Order By x.Name
              Select New MyViewModel() With {
                .Name = x.Name,
                .LastArticleDate = If(x.Articles.Count <> 0 AndAlso
                   x.Articles.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Dated).FirstOrDefault IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                   x.Articles.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Dated).FirstOrDefault.Dated.HasValue,
                   x.Articles.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Dated).FirstOrDefault.Dated.Value.ToShortDateString,
                   String.Empty)
              }
```

Comment: Why are you checking `HasValue` property on non-nullable `DateTime` property?! Is `Dated` really `DateTime?`?

Comment: Yes, DateTime is nullable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed `Article` class looks like that:

```
Public Class Article
  Public Property Dated as DateTime?
End Class
```

You should get `DateTime?` from database using EF, and then perform `ToShortDateString` as LINQ to Objects query. EF won't be able to translate `ToShortDateString` to proper SQL.

```
Dim query = From x In context.Languages
            Order By x.Name
            Select New With {
              .Name = x.Name,
              .LastArticleDate = x.Articles.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Dated).FirstOrDefault()
            }

Dim results = From x In query.AsEnumerable()
              Select New MyViewModel() With {
                .Name = x.Name,
                .LastArticleDate = If(!x.LastArticleDate.HasValue, "", x.LastArticleDate.ToShortDateString())
              }
```

Comment: Better yet, return LastArticleDate as a DateTime? and let your UI handle formatting the date. that way you won't need the results query and can just project directly into the MyViewModel.